# Angular JS ng-if on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using Angular JS wizard:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('WizardController', ['$scope', function($scope){

  $scope.user = {};

}]);
```

I have this dropdown here:

```
<select ng-model="user.agree">
              <option>Yes</option>
              <option>No</option>
          </select>
```

and if the user selects Yes, I want this link to appear:

```
<a ng-click="gotoNextStep()" 
ng-show="showNextButton()" 
ng-if="user.agree == 'Yes'">Next</a>
```

but when I goto this step, the button does not appear at all. I got `ng-if` to work on a `<p ng-if="user.agree == 'Yes'">Blah Blah Blah</p>` but for some reason its not working on a link.

the gotoNextStep and showNextButton are inside `myApp.directive('wizard', function(){` and my inputs and link are inside my `<wizard>` and I have ng-app and wizardController defined.

These are my functions (just in case):

```
 $scope.showNextButton = function () {
          return $scope.currentStepIndex > (1) && $scope.currentStepIndex < ($scope.steps.length - 1);
      }

$scope.gotoNextStep = function () {
          toggleSteps($scope.currentStepIndex + 1);
      }
```

Comment: What does your link markup look like?

Comment: can you share through plunkr or jsfiddle?

Comment: my link markup when i inspect the element looks like this `<!-- ngIf: user.agree == 'Yes' -->` weird

Comment: Please post your `wizard` directive, and the HTML that uses it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/68tW3/ (I cant seem to get angularjs working in fiddler, but my code is there

Comment: what is `wizard.html`?  here is an update of your fiddle, with angular working: http://jsfiddle.net/68tW3/1/  but, the directive template is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-if` is working fine.  Your problem is `ng-show`, which is hiding the element because it cannot find `showNextButton()`.  This is because the element is transcluded into the `step` directive where it no longer has the same scope as the `wizard`, where `showNextButton()` is defined.  Note that even if you removed `ng-show` and `ng-if`, `ng-click` wouldn't do anything either because `gotoNextStep` is also out of scope.

The `wizard` directive already has a Next button in the template, that shows the next step.  To achieve what you want, you could just modify the `showNextButton` function to return false if the user has not selected `Yes`.

```
$scope.showNextButton = function () {
    return $scope.user.agree == 'Yes' && $scope.currentStepIndex < $scope.steps.length;
}
```

This requires adding `user.agree` to the `wizard` scope..

```
scope: {
  user: '=',
  ...
},
```

and passing it in as an element attribute:

```
<wizard user="user" ...>
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KQP66/

Answer (score 0):

You need tu put a value to your option, `angularjs` won't take the text of the `option` but the `value`.

```
<select ng-model="user.agree">
              <option value="yes">Yes</option>
              <option value="no">No</option>
          </select>
```

Comment: jsfiddle.net/68tW3 (I cant seem to get angularjs working in fiddler, but my code is there –

Comment: Wrong angular link and no template `wizard.html`. It's normal that it doesn't works.